# If one li element is changed, will the whole list rerender?

Tags: reactjs

Here are the options

1. Virtual DOM manipulation is very fast, so react would rebuild the whole `<ul></ul>` quickly
2. By the help of VDOM only that specific `<li>` will be updated.
3. The entire virtual DOM gets updated.
4. The entire real DOM gets updated.
5. or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps are something like this:

1- Virtual DOM changes.

2- React compares the changes with old snapshot of Virtual DOM. (This snapshot is taken right before the update of the virtual DOM)

3- With the help of this comparison React figures out which components in the UI needs to be updated. (This process is called diffing)

4- React knows which components has been updated, then it replaces the original DOM nodes with the updated DOM node.

So, just the changes will be update on DOM

Comment: So the answer is 2. With the help of VDOM, only that specific `<li>` will be updated. right?

Comment: If the `<li>` has a unique key, yes. But if it has not the unique key, the whole `<ul>` tag will be rerender in real DOM

Answer (score 0):

If you set a unique `key` attribute on each `<li>`:

1. The whole virtual DOM is updated.
2. Every node in the new virtual DOM is compared to the node in the old one by the `key` attribute.
3. Only the changed nodes are replaced in the real DOM.

Comment: what if I do not set a unique `key`?

Comment: @HmEliusHossainHimel the whole `ul` will rerender because react can't know which `li` was changed and which not.